# is_home , is_front_page not working

Tags: conditional-tags

i tried many conditions to my footer.php section to include this function in my front page only and not on blog page...but it just pops up on both pages or none of them...can anyone explain the fault ?

```
 <?php if( is_home() && is_front_page()   ) : ?>
  <div id="blurbs">
    <ul>
  <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); ?>

   <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
   <div class="postwrapper">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>   <li style="display:inline; font-size: 20px; font-weight:light;"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<br class="clear">
  <li style=" font-size: 14px; font-weight:light;"><?php the_content(); ?></li>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile;?>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What's the output from `var_dump( is_home() );` and `var_dump( is_front_page() );` on both these pages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 <?php if( is_front_page() ) : ?>
```

is_home relates to the posts page according to your reading settings. is_front_page always returns true on the front page.

Comment: yeah but what should i do to saatisfy the condition in my question above...how to include it in only one page and not both pages.....??

Comment: Try the updated code and mark as accepted and give me up vote if works.

Comment: i already tried it without  wp_reset_query(); but it didnt work..

Comment: My solution relates purely to the use of conditional tags and works perfectly for me so the problem is at your end.

Answer (score 0):

- On the site front page, is_front_page() will always return TRUE,
  regardless of whether the site front page displays the blog posts
  index or a static page.
- On the blog posts index, is_home() will
  always return TRUE, regardless of whether the blog posts index is
  displayed on the site front page or a separate page.

So try following condition instead:

```
<?php if( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) && is_front_page()   ) : ?>
```

Comment: not working...still both pages show the content

Comment: <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>...this really solved my problem...wondering what more wonders can WP do :)

Comment: one more thing ..its written that do not use this until absolutely neccessary..will it casue any future errors or something else

Comment: @PiyushRawat `wp_reset_query()` is wrong. It is used with `query_posts` which you should never ever used. The correct way to reset `WP_Query` is `wp_reset_postdata()`. One note on `query_posts`, it breaks the main query and can cause the issue that you are having :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen will check with it too...atleast its functioning...btw thanks for the info

Answer (score -1):

wp_reset_query(); solved the problem...it was maybe due to loops running prior to this one..

Comment: As I said in another comment, your issue is probably related to the use of `query_posts`. Note, you should reset `WP_Query` with `wp_reset_postdata()`

Answer (score -1):

wp_reset_query(); is realy worked, if you use custom queries before call check front page

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! Could you [edit your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/306728/edit) using the [`edit` button above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/306728/edit) and explain where the question asker would put or use `wp_reset_query()` and why it may help them in this scenario?